# How to improve performance for serializing and deserializing a large object graph?

Tags: .net, performance, serialization, f#

I have a large object graph in .NET (F# as it happens) that I need to persist to disk and then will load again periodically for use in a calculation.

The performance of deserializing is more important (will be performed many times) than the seriliazing (will only be performed once) should that have a bearing on the answer.

Currently, I am using `FsPickler` and using their binary format. This is very convenient / easy-to-use but I am trying to get a handle on how much more performance I would get by customizing a serializer/deserializer...

One avenue I am considering is to persist and load from a small relational database (I have sqlite in mind). Should I expect this to be much faster?

Per request below, I have provided a slightly simplified version of the object graph that I am working on below:

## CODE

```
type Value = 
    | Float of float
    | String of string
    | Bool of bool

[<Struct>]
type Address (i:int, j:int, k:int) =
    member this.I = i
    member this.J = j
    member this.K = k


type Data = {
    Target:Address
    mutable SpecialIndex:int
    mutable Parameters1 : Value []
    mutable Parameters2 : Address []
    Check1 : bool
    Check2:bool
    Parent: Address option
}

type Persisted = 
    { 
      Inputs : Address []
      Outputs : Address []
      Aliases : Dictionary<string, Address>
      Mapping : Dictionary<string, int>
      Masters: Dictionary<Address, Value[]>
      BigCollection : Data [] }
```

1. The object that is persisted is an instance of `Persisted`.
2. The large size is most likely to come about due to `Persisted.BigCollection` being in the order of 10m or more items in the array.

Comment: Have you measured the time it takes and determined that there is a material performance problem?

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, I have profiled and the de-serialization time dominates the time taken to perform a calculation. My question above is an attempt to get guidance on where I should look should I choose to optimize and/or whether further material performance improvements should be expected.

Comment: Can you trade off space for speed?  Show us some of the object graph code looks like.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes - would be prepared to.

Comment: Depending on how much performance improvement you need, you might try a faster serializer like [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/?hl=en).

Comment: Is it possible to cache the object graph to save some deserialization?

Comment: @KaseySpeakman Unfortunately that's not likely to be the main usage. Main scenario is that the whole thing will need to be deserialized when needed. I am wondering whether a small sqlite db will be faster...

Comment: If you use a database, won't you still have to serialize/deserialize the individual nodes, or at least materialize/dematerialize them, ORM-style?  Also, how much performance improvement do you need?

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, a db will entail a bespoke mapping between the relational world and my object graph - much more work than the object graph serialization of FsPickle. That's why I'm trying to get a principles based understanding (before I do the work) of whether I should expect this approach to be materially faster (if at all).

Comment: What does the object graph look like?  Is it just an ordinary directed graph?  So far, we haven't seen any code that might give us an idea of the graph's structure.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Ordinary Directed Graph type structure - main list/array of items with some sub-items. Nothing special here just that it could "medium to large" in size which could lead to deserialization taking 10s-20s which I'm trying to optimize. I deliberately asked the question here (as opposed to StackOverflow) as I'm trying to get a more general answer without getting into the code

Comment: Ultimately, the way this question is going to get answered is to knock up some code and measure it.  If one of us is going to take some of our valuable time to do that, it would be nice if we were assured that we are not answering the wrong question.  Can you at least show us what a graph node looks like in F#?

Comment: @RobertHarvey see code added. I trust this is what you had in mind.

Comment: FsPickler is not meant to be fastest serializer. Try MessagePack.CLI / Protobuf, but you may have to give up Discriminated Union types to use them

Comment: @ArtemK. on a simplified test (without Discriminated Unions) protobuf-net package was a little slower (!) than FsPickler.

Answer (score 6):

> One avenue I am considering is to persist and load from a small relational database (I have sqlite in mind). Should I expect this to be much faster?

No, you should not expect this. Though it is not completely impossible, to my experience using a relational database for deserializing an object graph is seldom quicker than deserializing from a file. To my experience, relational databases can only help to increase performance when you can play out their strengths like indexing capabilites or managing of external data which is too big to be loaded into memory at once.

> I am trying to get a handle on how much more performance I would get by customizing a serializer/deserializer.

Whatever serializer/deserializer you use, the upper limit (and often the bottleneck) for performance is the I/O speed of your disk in "bytes per second". So look at the expected size in bytes of your serialized graph, divide it by the speed, and you will get a lower limit for the deserialization time. When the time your deserializer needs is near to that limit, the only resonable way to increase performance is to use a faster disk (like a modern SSD or something like that).

Comment: Thanks. Your second point makes a lotta sense! I have an SSD with "alleged" read speed of 728 mb/s. The example file I am testing on is 175mb in size and is taking 6.5s to deserialize...Sounds like there is room for improvement.

Comment: +1 for convincing me this question is answerable if interpreted the right way. I'd suggesting editing the off-topic-looking title to match this answer, since this clearly helped the OP, it's about to be closed (as the title, by itself, is obviously not a good question), and I don't feel I understand the question well enough to edit the title myself.